# What does the phrase "on the back" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I am confused about the meaning of the phrase "on the back" in the following sentence from the description of the game Gravity Rider Zero:

> Fight for first **on the back** of your wonderful space bike.

To me, the phrase can be replaced with "riding" here (riding your wonderful space bike). However, the phrase is generally used to mean "on the back of one's vehicle". I am wondering if the phrase has some other connotation that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Normally "on the back of your bike" would mean behind the rider. For example:

> My infant son was in a seat on the back of my bike.

or

> I brought the groceries home on the back of my bike.

But here they seem to mean that the rider is "on the back" of the bike. I suspect that this is an unintentional analogy with horse riding. The rider of a horse sits on the horse's back, on its spine.